# WPF RibbonComboBox Height

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribbon, ribbon-control, visualtreehelper

Ok, I would have thought this was a simple question, but apparently it's got me confused.

When I try to set the height of my RibbonComboBox, it's not moving actual size of it, just the box that surrounds it.

[image]

Here is my XAML:

```
<ribbon:RibbonComboBox                                                           
    DisplayMemberPath="CompanyCode" 
    Height="22" 
    Margin="0,0,0,-30" 
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
    Width="102">
  <ribbon:RibbonGallery SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Companies.SelectedItem,
                                                ValidatesOnDataErrors=true,
                                                NotifyOnValidationError=true }">
    <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Companies.Items, 
                                                        NotifyOnValidationError=true, 
                                                        ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}" />
  </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
</ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
```

I can change the height to 200 or 1 but the height never changes.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Eroc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Height is Hardcoded inside the style. It's probably because the control must behave in a Ribbon environment, which means it's must be standard.

One simple hack is to reach for the proper `Border` with the `VisualTreeHelper` and change his height.

Comment: You also have to do the same with one of the Grid (at least with Microsoft's System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon controls).

Answer (score 3):

You can change the height easily if you set the [DropDownHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonmenubutton.dropdownheight.aspx)